# Can not find symbol method metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

After integrating firebase in react native i am getting this error. I have searched and tried to change the gradle version as well moreover i have reinstalled the sdk build tools.

> Here is my build.gradle configurations

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

had the same issue using build tools 28.0.3,

first on android studio goto Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools

Tick "Show Packages Details"

UnTick the 28.0.3 to uninstall then ok

Tick again to install

[image]